# Use instantiated object from other method

Tags: c#, oop, object, instance

There is something about oop I have not been able to understand yet!
it's probably been asked already but I can't find it, the only example I found is about using singletons but it's not a suggested method.

Let's say this is my main code:

```
private void main()
{
    Process task1 = null;
    task1 = new Process();
    task1.StartInfo.FileName = something.bat;
    task1.StartInfo.Arguments = string.Format("10");
    task1.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
    task1.Start();
    task1.WaitForExit();
    Update();
}
```

then in another method I need to re-call the same object that has already been used:

```
private static void Update()
{
    task1.Start();
    task1.WaitForExit();
}
```

this code probably has bugs, but I just need to understand the instance concept.

Please any one can help?

Thanks and happy new year

Comment: Why not just pass it as parameter to `Update` method?

Comment: what you mean?can you make an example? because believe me..i tried hard....but passing values from method to method is not something i'm able to do easily....!

Comment: Rad/learn about variable `Scope`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare and instatiate it globally outside both functions, then you should be able use the same object,

```
Process task1 = null;
task1 = new Process();

private void main()
{
     task1.StartInfo.FileName = something.bat;
     ............
}

private void Update()
{
   task1.Start();
   task1.WaitForExit();
}
```

Or you can just pass the variable to your update method

```
void main()
{
            Process task1 = null;
            task1 = new Process();
            task1.StartInfo.FileName = something.bat;
            task1.StartInfo.Arguments = string.Format("10");
            task1.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
            task1.Start();
            task1.WaitForExit();
            Update(task1);
}
```

And in update method

```
private void update(Process taskin)
{
   taskin.Start();
   taskin.WaitForExit();
}
```

Comment: i just tried but it does not seem to work for me....i can't understand what mistake i'm doing maybe....thanks anyway for your answer

Comment: actually like you say...it's working only in the update method....and not in the main method....hmmmm...strange.

Comment: yes...i get Error 1 Ambiguity between 'ConsoleApplication1.Program.avvisotask' and 'ConsoleApplication1.Program.avvisotask' c:\users\utente\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\Program.cs 21 13

Forgive me...i translated most of it to english to make it clearer....so avvisotask is task1.

Comment: i like a lot the second way you used.....that also someone else posted but then removed....
Thanks very much....
is this a good way to proceed?

Comment: Yes it is, thats how you use the same variable

Comment: yes...it worked i believe....i will test it later....but Vs is not giving any red lines.....so i guess it's working...!! thanks very much Sajeetharan!!

Answer (score 0):

To answer you question about the instance concept. Its more about the scope of your variables than instance concept.

```
private void main()
{
    Process task1 = null;
    task1 = new Process();
    task1.StartInfo.FileName = something.bat;
    task1.StartInfo.Arguments = string.Format("10");
    task1.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
    task1.Start();
    task1.WaitForExit();
    Update();
}
```

In the code above, `Process task1 = null;` initialises the variable then you set it by `task1 = new Process();` on the next line, as you are doing this in the `void Main()` method, now these variables are scoped to this method.

The `Update()` method is a completely seperate method and has no visibility of the variables initialised in the `Main()` method. if you need a variable that will be used in many methods on the same class, sajeetharan answer is correct, I will add to it by saying that in your situation, try declaring a private field if possible.

to read more about scopes check out - [Variables and method scopes in .Net](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973875.aspx)

Comment: Thanks Preet!
I thought there was an easier way to make variables instantiated from objects global! I guess the easier method would be to use global static variables.....but in case you want to do something on old code, it's not that easy....!
Thanks very much!

Answer (score -1):

If you want to operate only on a single object throughout your code, you can use a Singleton class:

```
public class SingleProc
{
  private static SingleProc instance;
  private SingleProc() { }
  public Process Proc { get; set; }
  public static void RunTillExit()
  {
    Instance.Proc.Start();
    Instance.Proc.WaitForExit();
  }
  public static SingleProc Instance
  {
    get
    {
      if (instance == null)
      {
        instance = new SingleProc();
      }
      return instance;
    }
  }
}
```

Set the properties:

```
SingleProc.Instance.Proc.StartInfo.FileName = "something.bat";
SingleProc.Instance.Proc.StartInfo.Arguments = string.Format("10");
SingleProc.Instance.Proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
```

and everywhere you need to: call `RunTillExit`:

```
SingleProc.RunTillExit();
```